# Add an arrow with filled head to ggplot by geom_label_repel

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I want to add an arrow with a filled head to a ggplot object by using the `geom_label_repel` function. I thought that I could use: `arrow.fill = 'black'` like I do with the `geom_segment`, but it does not work in the `geom_label_repel`. Is it another way to get a filled arrow?

The reason why I use the `geom_label_repel` is that it was the only way I managed to start the arrow at the border of the label. If this coordinate can be found in another way, I could use the `geom_segment` instead.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

dmax <- iris %>%
  filter(Sepal.Length == max(Sepal.Length))

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel(data=dmax, aes(label = 'max'), 
                   box.padding = unit(.25, 'lines'), 
                   point.padding = unit(1.5, 'lines'), 
                   arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.25, 'cm'), type = 'closed')) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=3, xend=max(Sepal.Width), y=0, yend=max(Sepal.Width)), 
               arrow=arrow(length = unit(0.25, 'cm'), type = 'closed'), 
               arrow.fill = 'black')
```

Comment: `ggrepel::geom_label_repel`'s arrow parameter is provided by the `grid` package. There is no `arrow.fill` option in `grid::arrow`, so I don't think you can fill the arrow from `ggrepel::geom_label_repel`.

Comment: also geom_segment uses `arrow` from `grid`, yet it can fill the arrow head. You will probably have to dig into grob tables and whatnot. I'm trying to investigate how `geom_segment` does it

Comment: @GGamba may help your investigations.  somehow related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60446727/alpha-aesthetic-shows-arrows-skeleton-instead-of-plain-shape-how-to-prevent-i  it seems to me that ggrepel must change the grid draw function how to draw an arrow - it seems that it does actually 'fill' the arrowhead...

Answer (score 7):

We can see from `GeomSegment$draw_panel` that the `arrow.fill` value in `geom_segment` is passed to the `fill` parameter in `grid::segmentsGrob`. The same modification can be applied to `ggrepel::geom_label_repel`:

```
ggplot(data = iris, 
       aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel2(data=. %>% 
                      filter(Sepal.Length == max(Sepal.Length)), 
                    aes(label = 'max'), 
                    box.padding = unit(.25, 'lines'), 
                    point.padding = unit(1.5, 'lines'), 
                    arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.25, 'cm'), type = 'closed'),
                    arrow.fill = "green") +
  geom_segment(aes(x=3, xend=max(Sepal.Width), y=0, yend=max(Sepal.Width)), 
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.25, 'cm'), type = 'closed'), 
               arrow.fill = 'red')
```

[image: result]

Code for modified ggproto object & geom function:

```
GeomLabelRepel2 <- ggproto(
  "GeomLabelRepel2",
  GeomLabelRepel,
  draw_panel = function (self, data, panel_scales, coord, parse = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE, 
                         box.padding = 0.25, label.padding = 0.25, point.padding = 1e-06, 
                         label.r = 0.15, label.size = 0.25, segment.colour = NULL, 
                         segment.size = 0.5, segment.alpha = NULL, min.segment.length = 0.5, 
                         arrow = NULL, arrow.fill = NULL, # add arrow.fill parameter
                         force = 1, nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 0, xlim = c(NA, NA), 
                         ylim = c(NA, NA), max.iter = 2000, direction = "both", seed = NA) 
  {
    lab <- data$label
    if (parse) {
      lab <- parse(text = as.character(lab))
    }
    if (!length(which(ggrepel:::not_empty(lab)))) {
      return()
    }
    nudges <- data.frame(x = data$x + nudge_x, y = data$y + nudge_y)
    nudges <- coord$transform(nudges, panel_scales)
    data <- coord$transform(data, panel_scales)
    nudges$x <- nudges$x - data$x
    nudges$y <- nudges$y - data$y
    limits <- data.frame(x = xlim, y = ylim)
    limits <- coord$transform(limits, panel_scales)
    limits$x[is.na(limits$x)] <- c(0, 1)[is.na(limits$x)]
    limits$y[is.na(limits$y)] <- c(0, 1)[is.na(limits$y)]
    if (is.character(data$vjust)) {
      data$vjust <- compute_just(data$vjust, data$y)
    }
    if (is.character(data$hjust)) {
      data$hjust <- compute_just(data$hjust, data$x)
    }
    if(is.null(arrow.fill)) { # define fill if arrow.fill is specified
      arrow.fill.gp <- grid::gpar()
    } else {
      arrow.fill.gp <- grid::gpar(fill = arrow.fill)
    }
    ggplot2:::ggname("geom_label_repel", 
                     grid::gTree(limits = limits, 
                                 data = data, 
                                 lab = lab, 
                                 nudges = nudges, 
                                 box.padding = ggrepel:::to_unit(box.padding), 
                                 label.padding = ggrepel:::to_unit(label.padding), 
                                 point.padding = ggrepel:::to_unit(point.padding), 
                                 label.r = ggrepel:::to_unit(label.r), 
                                 label.size = label.size, 
                                 segment.colour = segment.colour,
                                 segment.size = segment.size, 
                                 segment.alpha = segment.alpha, 
                                 min.segment.length = ggrepel:::to_unit(min.segment.length), 
                                 arrow = arrow, 
                                 gp = arrow.fill.gp, # add gp
                                 force = force, 
                                 max.iter = max.iter, 
                                 direction = direction, 
                                 seed = seed, 
                                 cl = "labelrepeltree"))
  }
)

geom_label_repel2 <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", 
                               position = "identity", parse = FALSE, ..., box.padding = 0.25, 
                               label.padding = 0.25, point.padding = 1e-06, label.r = 0.15, 
                               label.size = 0.25, segment.colour = NULL, segment.color = NULL, 
                               segment.size = 0.5, segment.alpha = NULL, min.segment.length = 0.5, 
                               arrow = NULL, arrow.fill = NULL, # add arrow.fill parameter
                               force = 1, max.iter = 2000, nudge_x = 0, nudge_y = 0, 
                               xlim = c(NA, NA), ylim = c(NA, NA), na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                               direction = c("both", "y", "x"), seed = NA, 
                               inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  if (!missing(nudge_x) || !missing(nudge_y)) {
    if (!missing(position)) {
      stop("Specify either `position` or `nudge_x`/`nudge_y`", 
           call. = FALSE)
    }
  }
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomLabelRepel2, # change geom
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = list(parse = parse, box.padding = ggrepel:::to_unit(box.padding), 
                      label.padding = ggrepel:::to_unit(label.padding), point.padding = ggrepel:::to_unit(point.padding), 
                      label.r = ggrepel:::to_unit(label.r), label.size = label.size, 
                      segment.colour = segment.color %||% segment.colour, 
                      segment.size = segment.size, segment.alpha = segment.alpha, 
                      min.segment.length = ggrepel:::to_unit(min.segment.length), 
                      arrow = arrow, arrow.fill = arrow.fill, # add arrow.fill parameter
                      na.rm = na.rm, force = force, max.iter = max.iter, 
                      nudge_x = nudge_x, nudge_y = nudge_y, xlim = xlim, 
                      ylim = ylim, direction = match.arg(direction), seed = seed, 
                      ...))
}
```

Comment: seems almost worth a pull request ;)

Comment: @Z.Lin do you have any tutorials how to make these complex functions?

Comment: This is great. `ggrepel` is a great package but a lot more flexibility should be added to it. Like changing the font color without affecting the leader line color (almost 2 am and I am pulling my hair trying to figure that out). Anyway, nice answer!!!

Answer (score 1):

While I would definitely go for the solution of `Z.Lin`, I just want to add a hack, which I usually apply, when I am not satisfied with the output of `ggplot` and I am too lazy to fix `ggprotos` (which are nightmarish to work with if you work with them only every now and then).

To make a long story short, here's my usual approach:

1. Convert the `ggplot` object to a grob.
2. Find the corresponding grob which I want to change.
3. Change it.
4. Use `grid.draw` to plot the whole object with the modified `grob`.

In our case this would look like this (N.B. I increased the distance to the label to be able to see the arrow in the first place):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
library(grid)

dmax <- iris %>%
  filter(Sepal.Length == max(Sepal.Length))

gp <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_label_repel(data=dmax, aes(label = 'max'), 
                   box.padding = unit(2, 'lines'), 
                   point.padding = unit(1.5, 'lines'), 
                   arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, 'cm'), type = 'closed'))

### 1. Convert to grob
ggp <- ggplotGrob(gp)

### 2. Find the `arrow` grob
## panel is the main plotting area of the ggplot
pan_idx <- grep("panel", ggp$layout[, "name"])
## the repel grob
repel_idx <- grep("repel", names(ggp$grobs[[pan_idx]]$children))

### 3. Change it, i.e. add a `gpar` with a fill
ggp$grobs[[pan_idx]]$children[[repel_idx]]$gp <- gpar(fill = "green")

### 4. Draw it
grid.draw(ggp)
```

---

### Why I'd go with `Z.Lin's` proposal

As you can see, this approach relies heavily on some assumptions:

1. The structure of `ggplotGrob`. As this is an internal representation, we do not have any guarantee that this stays stable with future changes to `ggplot2`.
2. The structure is highly dependent on the plot you draw. Add some facets and it will require again a lot of skimming through the structure of the grobs to find the relevant one.
3. We rely on the fact that the `repel` grob's name contains the string `"repel"`. This is again some internal convention, which may change over time and is thus not reliable on the long turn.

Bottom line is: this approach works nicely for a lot of quick fixes in case we need to change the appearance of a plot, but is by no means stable and always needs some manual browsing through the **internal** grob representation, which makes the solution fragile. However, I just wanted ot add it here as a maybe useful addition to your toolbox.

[image: Scatterplot with an arrow with a color filled head]