# Create a new custom point shape for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes, geom

I would like to use a new point shape on ggplot2, and use it the same way as geom_point().

I know that [ggstar](https://github.com/xiangpin/ggstar) implements some new shapes, but I would like to use the following:

[image: Desired shape]

It's created just combining a circle with a rect, creating this new shape

[image: joining shapes]

I think the code of ggstar to create the shapes is in the following link, but I couldn't understand and recreate it:

https://github.com/xiangpin/ggstar/blob/master/R/primitive.R

I see [Allan Cameron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12500315/allan-cameron) created a new grob on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64034235/15611828), but I don't know how to recreate this new shape, and add the ability to use `angle` argument

Comment: Show your efforts in creating the shape. That's just copy paste from the linked answer.

Comment: Did you try `rectGrob()` + `circleGrob()` + `gTree()`? Where the circle centre corresponds to the mid point of the rectangle's bottom line?

Answer (score 4):

Building on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64034235/12993861) from @AllanCameron and the suggestion from @Friede in his comment here is one possible approach to achieve your desired result which also allows for an `angle` argument:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(grid)
library(ggpmisc)

custom_shape <- function(size, angle = 0) {
  vp <- viewport(angle = angle)
  grobTree(
    rectGrob(
      x = unit(0.5, "npc"),
      y = unit(0.5, "npc"),
      width = unit(size, "mm"),
      height = unit(size / 2, "mm"),
      gp = gpar(fill = "blue"),
      vjust = 0,
      vp = vp
    ),
    circleGrob(
      x = unit(0.5, "npc"),
      y = unit(0.5, "npc"),
      r = unit(size / 2, "mm"),
      gp = gpar(fill = "red"),
      vp = vp
    )
  )
}

# Plot 10 random points
set.seed(69)

tibble(
  x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10),
  shape = purrr::map2(
    sample(seq(10)), 
    seq(0, 360, length.out = 10),
    custom_shape
  )
) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_grob(aes(x, y, label = shape))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Is it possible to combine them to be just one shape?