How can I assign an SVG file as a custom vertex shape to igraph in R?
I have created a hand-drawn, nicely-looking node in Inkscape. The SVG file consists of two paths, a circle, which is the internal part of the node, and the frame surrounding it. I would like to use it in R as a replacement for the regular vertex shapes available with igraph. I thought about using an SVG file to allow proper scaling. Is it possible to do so?
EXTRA: It would be nice to add a further customizability layer, by giving the two paths a different user-defined colour, but I can also survive with making multiple SVG files with preset colour combinations.
I looked through the available documentation and SO questions but could not find any straightforward way to deal with this.

This might be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/q/64032845/680068 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/77471412/680068
